# Referencing a Range in Excel

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I have named the range C6:C13 'Date'. This is a dynamic range(the start date will vary) and in practice, it will be a very long column. E6 will be created from C6, so the cell E6 will be '=Date'. Rather than dragging this formula down a few thousand rows, I wish to be able to enter '=Date' in column E, and for it to fill as many rows as are filled in in Column C. The problem is that the amount of rows will vary, and if I just enter '=Date' in all of the rows down to 100k or whatever, of course '#VALUE!' will be entered in many rows below(I realise this is a non-issue in many cases but it's a big problem for me).

So is there a way to reference '=Date' in Column E, in only as many rows that are filled in column C?

Answer (score 1):

```
=ifError(Date,"")
```

Should do what you want if I'm not mistaken